# Having trouble setting up a custom java font

Tags: java, fonts

Java fonts are wonky.

Here is my current coding, this is just a simple method that gets the font from the the file, then returns it, but I am missing something, I just don't know what... Can anyone help?

```
private Font createFont(){
    try {
        URL fontUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/Fonts/aesysmatt.ttf");
        Font mFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontUrl.openStream());
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
        return mFont;
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is what my errors are looking like:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at disparity.characterCreation.ColoredButton.createFont(ColoredButton.java:21)
    at disparity.characterCreation.ColoredButton.<init>(ColoredButton.java:37)
    at disparity.characterCreation.StartScreen.initialize(StartScreen.java:93)
    at disparity.characterCreation.StartScreen.<init>(StartScreen.java:61)
    at disparity.characterCreation.StartScreen$2.run(StartScreen.java:48)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `fontURL` is not `null`? This is likely to be the problem here. IMHO the path to your resource is incorrect (try `/Fonts/aesysmatt.ttf`?)

Comment: The `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/Fonts/aesysmatt.ttf");` statement sets the path to the directory of the .class file. The actual setup here looks like this: `disparity/characterCreation/` In here is where my classes are located, and in the `disparity/characterCreation/res/Font` dir is where my `aesysmatt.ttf` is located. The program doesn't know to enter `res` without my telling, so that wouldn't work, thanks though.

Comment: Try and use the absolute path, then -- but am I correct? ie, is `fontURL` null?

Comment: Yes. How would I go about doing absolute path?

Comment: Provided your class is in package `foo.bar`, that would be `/foo/bar/res/Fonts/aesysmatt.ttf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not to sure on how I did it, but here was the error line in the end once I fixed it, hope it helps someone.

```
    URL fontUrl = getClass().getResource("res/Fonts/aesymatt.ttf");
```

It must have been because it was loading the classLoader on the original, which wouldn't really make any sense.